# Can I put a comma after "may I ask" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

Can I put a comma after "may I ask" in a question ?
For example:

May I ask, do you help people with applications ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you not only can but ought to include a comma where you have "May I ask" tacked onto a complete question:

> May I ask, do you help people with applications?

> Do you help people with applications, may I ask?

By contrast, you wouldn't include the comma if the question was indirect (a subordinate clause introduced by "if"/"whether"):

> May I ask whether you help with applications?

Comment: I understand, thank you so much.

Comment: Why not use a colon?

Comment: Yes, a colon would be an acceptable alternative, as would a dash, although I think a comma is most usual. What would be wrong would be to have no punctuation at all between "May I ask" and "do you help people with applications".